# Custom Repeater with hiractial Databinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, custom-controls

Im using a Custom NestedRepeater Control for ASP.NET which can be found [on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/nestedrepeater.aspx)

The source is in c# which i have converted to vb and plugged into my solution, so far so good. The problem, im having is databinding to the repeater, my code behind looks like this...

```
    '' get all pages
    Dim navPages As DataSet = Navigation.getMenuStructure()
    navPages.Relations.Add(navPages.Tables(0).Columns("ID"), navPages.Tables(0).Columns("ParentID"))
    NestedRepeaterNavigation.RelationName = RelationName
    NestedRepeaterNavigation.DataSource = navPages
    NestedRepeaterNavigation.RowFilterTop = "ParentID is null"
    NestedRepeaterNavigation.DataBind()
```

Then in the item template of my custom repeater im trying the following...

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <img src="/pix.gif" height="10" width="<%#(Container.Depth * 10)%>">
<%# (Container.DataItem as DataRow)["DESCRIPTION"]%>
<%# (Container.NbChildren != 0 ? "<small><i>(" + Container.NbChildren.ToString() +")</i></small>" "") %><small><i></i></small>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The databinding falls over; firstly that 'as DataRow' says it was expecting an ')'. And secondly that '!=' identifier expected.

Is this due to the translation from c#, should the databinding be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I've not programmed in VB.net for long (about 3 years) but I know that `AS` is not applicable in VB.net  you need `ctype` to cast `Container.DataItem` like

`CType(Container.DataItem, DataRow)`.

you can also try `DirectCast(Container.DataItem, DataRow)` but I don't think this will work.

Also for inequality comparison you can use

`Not Container.DataItem = 0`

but not `!=`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you show me how i would cast this?